# Can the negative terminal of a class B amplifier be connected to the ground instead of the negative supply?

Tags: analog, linear-regulator

I have a number of related questions highlighted in ***italic bold.***

Here is a class B amplifier we saw in most of the textbooks (note that the negative terminal is connected to the negative supply. Refer to circuit 1

[image]
Circuit 1

***Q1: However is it possible to connect the negative terminal of a class B amplifier to the ground instead as illustrated in circuit 2?***

[image]Circuit 2

***Q2: If the circuit is connected to the ground (circuit 2), can the output voltage has a zero DC value?***
(I suppose it cannot. The output in circuit 2 should have a non-zero DC value)

If we want an output voltage with zero DC, there are two possible methods to do it.

Method 1 (circuit 3)

1. Connect the negative terminal of a class B linear amplifier to the negative supply.
2. The output voltage at the drains of both PMOS and NMOS already has a zero DC.

[image]Circuit 3

Method 2 (circuit 4)

1. Connect the negative terminal of a class B linear amplifier to the ground
2. The voltage at the drains of the PMOS and NMOS has a non-zero DC
3. Use a coupling capacitor to filter out the DC value

[image]Circuit 4

***Q3: Are method 1 and method 2 equivalent if the purpose is to get an output voltage with zero DC?***

***Q4: What are the pros and cons of method 1 and method 2? Which method is usually preferred? (assume the DC input power for both methods is the same, i.e. Vcc1 in circuit 3 is half of Vcc in circuit 4)***

Thanks.

Comment: Show us that you've at least tried to do your own homework before dumping it here...

Comment: @brhans Sorry that it is not a homework problem. I just found something not understand when I am doing simulation. Grateful if you could indicate which parts of the questions should I make clearer in order to deserve an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Correcting terminology - The capacitor in the last circuit is a coupling capacitor, not a bypass capacitor.  A bypass capacitor is generally connected between supply and ground.

Comment: @PeterBennet Thanks. I have corrected it.

Comment: Circuit 4 needs input voltage "lifting" with Vdd/2...

Answer (score 2):

Single-supply and dual-supply variants of a complimentary-symmetry amplifier have been described.

In the single supply version, with Vcc/2 present at the output, capacitor coupling is a must.

In the dual-supply version, with the output being at 0 V DC, direct coupling is permissible.

Comment: In single supply cases, a bridged arrangement does not require a capacitor. You can examine the TDA8551 IC, for an example case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, jonk. I didn't even think of that!

Comment: @jonk, I think we can consider the 'bridge arrangement' as a further development of the 'complementary arrangement'. Both they consist of two parts having a property of resistance or voltage. They implement the general 'differential idea' - to change simultaneously and oppositely the properties of the two parts. In the complementary pair (potentiometer, two dual transistors), we change the resistances of the two halves vertically. In the bridge, we change the voltages of the two voltage dividers (half bridges) horizontally. Beautiful and fully symmetrical idea...

Comment: Also, we can consider the bridge arrangement as a complementary stage where the load is connected not to a "static" but to an oppositely changing ground. So, the first complementary stage (half bridge) serves as a driving voltage source while the second complementary stage (another half bridge) serves as a "movable ground"...

Comment: Hi Circuit fantasist, Your eye-opening perspective makes things easy to understand. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual question about the implementation of the complementary idea (figuratively called, "push-pull").

We are talking about a voltage (here, "source") follower. To make it fully symmetrical (bipolar), we assemble the circuit of two complementary halves; thus it becomes a "complementary voltage follower". The one of them (NMOS) works during the positive half wave; the other (PMOS) - during the negative half wave.

The most natural way to do it is to "stick" two dual voltage followers, each of them supplied by its own voltage source (the so-called "split supply"). But, unfortunately, we need two supply sources.

If we have only one supply:) but still want to make such a complementary follower, we have to "shift up" the input voltage variations with Vdd/2 before applying them to the joined gates... and then to "shift down" the output variatons with Vdd/2 before applying them to the load. Thus the full range Vdd of the power supply will be utilized.

Voltage variations can be "shifted", according to KVL,  by connecting a constant voltage source (e.g., a battery) in series with the input and output voltage sources... in the same (for the input) and in the opposite direction (for the output). It is inconvenient to use many "floating" voltage sources in electronic circuits. That is why, we implement them by "charge" capacitors... called "coupling capacitors". Of course, they have to be somehow continuously charged.

In addition to this significant "shift" of the input and output voltage, we have to slightly "shift" (bias) the gates with the MOSFET threshold voltage "up" (for NMOS) and "down"  (for PMOS).

Comment: Hi Circuit fantasist, Thank you very much for your most lucid answer.